# Does Oracle SQL database optimize by value?

Tags: java, sql, database, performance, oracle

I know (or think I know) that using things like prepared statements can help future executions of the same query execute faster. However, I was wondering, if you're using prepared statements but the actual values are the same every time, will it then also additionally optimize using the value?

To give a little more context, I want to test performance for a service request that uses an underlying database. The easy route would be to send in the same data each time. The more arduous route would be to ensure the data values were different each time. However, in either case, the same SQL query would be generated -- just the values would be different. So, will these scenarios end up testing the same thing or something different because of potential DB optimization?

I've tried to research this topic but I feel like a lot of what I'm reading is over my head. Any good links for someone that knows little about DB optimization would also be welcomed in addition to the central question.

Comment: How about to try it to see what difference it makes?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have both limited time and doing the "new value every time" route will be time consuming (because the data needs to meet certain conditions). Also, doing that will limit other testing I can do in this area (because of the limited time granted). I was hoping an answer to the question might help me to decide how I should dedicate my time.

Comment: If you are finding it hard to time a few queries with different values, you are doing something wrong.  After you have done the first one it should take you 5 minutes to try it repeatedly and with different values.

Comment: You're correct that, all other things being equal, prepared statements can give you a performance boost. Oracle has a result cache for situations when the prepared statement parameter values are the same. It also has a statement cache so if it gets the same statement but with different values it doesn't have to compile the statement and determine the query plan each time. As with all cache implementations, there are tons of disclaimers. A good place to start learning is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/stmtcach.htm).

Comment: Also please heed the advice about testing from @PeterLawrey. If your data has to meet certain conditions, that's all the more reason to exercise as many of them as possible.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If you don't want to answer the question, that's fine. But even if I did these tests, it still wouldn't necessarily answer this question. There could be the possibility that caching might happen but be negligible on the results for what I'm doing. So, I'd still want to know for sure, just for my own knowledge and/or future application.

Comment: @EdGibbs Thanks for the info about the result cache and the link. That will help increase my understanding. It's not that the data conditions imply a ton of branching situations (though there is some of that), but that creating a set of data must meet certain validation that is not trivial to generate for thousands or millions of values. It does seem I will have to do that, though.

Comment: @AHungerArtist Conversely, you could know the answer that it does some caching or not, but knowing this might not make any difference in a real use case.  There is many levels of aching so you can be sure there will be at least disk caching, some query caching, but how much difference it makes can only be determined by measuring it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, that is true. I think I should do the work to create the different data sets since that will most closely mirror real use cases.

Comment: @AHungerArtist In theory, theory and practice are the same, in practice they are not.  So often I think that something should or should not make a difference, but when I test it the results are not what I expected. (They match more than half the time ;)

Comment: tell us more about the service request

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I'm not concerned about the service request in this question, just how the Oracle database works.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you are doing and measuring.  I would expect, though, that you'd need to use different values in order to get realistic results.

**Caching**

If you send the same values every time, you can probably guarantee that the particular row(s) that you're interested in are always going to be cached (in the buffer cache, in the file system cache, in the SAN cache, etc.) which is probably not terribly realistic if the set of possible inputs is large.  On the other hand, if there are a small number of potential inputs and you're reasonably confident that the rows of interest will always be cached (for example, if you know that some other activity that takes place just before your service is called will cause the data you're interested in to be cached in memory before your service is called) then perhaps this is a realistic assumption.

**Optimization**

Ignoring caching, we can look at how the optimizer would treat the two cases.  If you are generating SQL queries with embedded literals (a bad practice that is particularly harmful in Oracle but one that is very common), then you are generating different SQL statements.  As far as Oracle is concerned

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp
 WHERE deptno = 10
```

is a completely different statement from

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp
 WHERE deptno = 20
```

There are some settings (i.e. `cursor_sharing`) you can tweak to ask Oracle to treat these two as identical queries (by having Oracle force them into using bind variables) but that is not without its own downsides and is generally only recommended when you're trying to apply a band-aid to a poorly written application while you work on refactoring the application to use bind variables properly.

Assuming that you are generating queries using bind variables in your application, preparing the statement, and then binding different values before executing the query multiple times, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM emp
 WHERE deptno = :1
```

then you get into the realm of histograms, bind variable peeking, and adaptive cursor sharing.  This can get pretty involved and depends heavily on the version of Oracle you're using, the edition you're using, and how you've configured the optimizer to work.  I'll try to give a simplified high-level overview here-- if you want to delve too much deeper into one of these, we'll probably want a separate question.

*Histograms*

By default, the optimizer assumes that data is equally spaced and equally likely.  So, for example, if the `deptno` column has 50 distinct values, the optimizer assumes by default that each value is equally likely.  That's probably a pretty reasonable assumption for most columns but it's obviously not reasonable for all columns.  If I have a table with all active duty military members, for example, and one of the columns is `birth_year`, there will be far more rows with a `birth_year` of 1994 (20 years ago) than 1934 (80 years ago).  In these cases, you gather histograms on the column in question in order to tell the optimizer that the data isn't evenly distributed and to let the optimizer gather information about which values are more common and how common they are.

The optimizer doesn't care about the values you are passing for your bind variable values unless there is a histogram on one of the columns in your predicate (I'll ignore for the moment the possibility that you are passing a value that is out of range).

*Bind variable peeking*

If you do have a histogram on one or more columns, then Oracle (9.1 and later if memory serves) will "peek" at the first value that is passed in for a bind variable and use that value with the histogram to determine the best plan for all subsequent executions.  This works reasonably well the vast majority of the time but it occasionally leads to hair-pullingly painful problems (and much swearing) when Oracle peeks at a "bad" value and generates a plan that is efficient for that one execution but terrible for all future executions.  This is summed up by Tom Kyte's story about [the database that has to be restarted if it's rainy on a Monday morning](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2012/05/another-debugging-story.html).  If you have a histogram on the column and different values that you might pass in would likely benefit from different query plans, you'd likely want to take bind variable peeking into consideration to determine if passing in values in a different order created any performance issues.

*Adaptive cursor sharing*

In recent versions (if memory serves 11.1 and later) and depending on your configuration, Oracle can use [adaptive cursor sharing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/adaptive-cursor-sharing-11gr1.php) to maintain multiple query plans for a single statement and to use the most appropriate version for the particular bind variable value that is passed in.  This is a much more sophisticated version of bind variable peeking that peeks for each set of values you pass in and figures out whether it is close enough to some other set of values to use the previously generated plan or whether it needs to compute a new plan for the new set of values.  Figuring out what constitutes "close enough" and how this interacts with various features for ensuring plan stability is a rather involved topic in its own right.

Answer (score -1):

you could use db caching

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-caching-pooling-088320.html

if the app is making network roundtrip and caculating results, that will still eat considerable time

Comment: Your answer is link only, would you mind editing your post to include the relevant quoted section from the text?

Comment: the material just explains "how" to do db caching and op did ask for a link - the real answer to op's question is not answered by the link, database is just one part of the entire app

Comment: Very true...but stackoverflow is a reference site as well and people can/will come to this question as they need (many of these questions and answers appear in google).  Links always run the risk of going stale, better to have the relevant components in the answer